# Compare Oracle database in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How to compare two Oracle databases in SQL developer like we do in RedGate tool.

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't use the Red Gate tool?

Comment: Red Gate tool is not free-ware

Answer (score 2):

We can use Database Diff in SQL Developer.

You can check the following link - http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/09/sql-developer-database-diff-compare-objects-from-multiple-schemas/